# MVC4 Show a description field when selecting 'other' from a dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, html-select

I have a simple problem that just eludes me. I've seen lots of examples but just can't put my finger on the correct code. The problem: I need to show a text input field only if 'Other' is selected from a dropdownlist.

My JavaScript:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create Client";
    var showGenderDescription = false;
    var showSettingDescription = false;
}

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#GenderId').change(function () {
            if ($("#GenderId").val() == 3) {
            showGenderDescription = true;

            }
        });

        $("#SettingId").change(function () {
            if ($("#SettingId").val() == 1) {
                showGenderDescription = true;
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

My View Code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GenderId, "Gender")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("GenderId", (SelectList)ViewBag.GenderId, "--Select One--", new { id = "GenderId"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GenderId)
    </div>

    @if(showGenderDescription)
    {
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GenderDescription)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.GenderDescription)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GenderDescription)
        </div>
    }
}
```

The dropdownlist works correctly on post back to the controller but I would like to show the description input box. Haven't seen anything out there that would duplicate this type of behavior (not in my searches anyway). As always any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you've set up `showGenderDescription`, it will only be checked once.  To bind it to any changes, use a class (or similar) to wrap the "other" input field:

```
<div class="gender-description">
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GenderDescription)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.GenderDescription)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GenderDescription)
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you can show/hide it inside the `change` JS function(s):

```
if ($("#GenderId").val() == 3) {
    $(".gender-description").show();
} else {
    $(".gender-description").hide();
}
```

Comment: @Vignesh While your answer is also correct using css I have to give this one to McGarnagle because he got to it first but I'm up ticking it because I'm sure someone else will find it useful as well.

Comment: When the page first loads the description field is showing and only disappears when I make a selection in the ddl of something other than 'Other'. Anyway to hide this from the start?

Comment: Solved the problem  with the following code:  $(window).bind("load", function (event) {
            $(".gender-description").hide();
        });

Answer (score 1):

I added a parent div for the editors and changed the Jquery functionalities. Please let me know if there is any issues

**Script**

```
<script>
    $(function () {
    $("#ShowGenderDescriptionContainer").css("display","none");
        $('#GenderId').change(function () {
            if ($("#GenderId").val() == 3) {
        $("#ShowGenderDescriptionContainer").css("display","block");
            }
        });
        $("#SettingId").change(function () {
            if ($("#SettingId").val() == 1) {
                $("#ShowGenderDescriptionContainer").css("display","block");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GenderId, "Gender")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("GenderId", (SelectList)ViewBag.GenderId, "--Select One--", new { id = "GenderId"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GenderId)
        </div>
        <div id = "ShowGenderDescriptionContainer">
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GenderDescription)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.GenderDescription)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GenderDescription)
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```